# Cache-Control policy for external Next.js Image coming from AWS CloudFront is not efficient for Google Lighthouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, cache-control, lighthouse, nextjs-image

I'm trying to optimize my Next.js app by fixing all the issues reported by Google Lighthouse.

One of the most important pitfalls it has right now regards to images:

[image: Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy]

As per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching), Next.js automatically does so for media in the `static` folder

> Next.js automatically adds caching headers to immutable assets served from /_next/static including JavaScript, CSS, static images, and other media.

As all of those problematic images are coming from an API, which serves them from AWS CloudFront, I can't find a way to fix the problem.

I guess adding the suggested `Cache-Control` policy in CloudFront may help but I don't know

1.) If that's the right solution
2.) How to do so in AWS Console

Answer (score 6):

> Next.js automatically adds caching headers to immutable assets served from /_next/static including JavaScript, CSS, static images, and other media.

This is not the case when you are using `next export` and deploying a static site to S3 & CloudFront, see [unsupported features](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#supported-features) (although they do not state that explicitly). What you can do is set these [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers yourself manually with [S3 object metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html). This is a preferred way for a next.js app because you can specify the headers for each object separately.

Generally (see [Caching best practices & max-age gotchas](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/)) you should add `max-age=31536000,public,immutable` directives to the whole `_next/static` folder since these will have the hash appended to the file name, thus the cache gets invalidated on every new change.

Other than that it's for you to manage & depends on what type of app you're building, but it's common practice to set the HTML documents to `public,max-age=0,must-revalidate` (even `no-cache,no-store`). Since you are using CloudFront it's fine to keep them in the edge cache as long as u have a proper invalidation set up.

You also might have [non-statically imported images](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#src) with `src="<path string>"`, these also won't be exported to the `_next/static` folder so if you want to add `long max-age` & `immutable content` to these you have to manage the versioning/hashing yourself to invalidate properly when the images change.

##### With AWS Console

Checkout [editing object metadata in the Amazon S3 console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/add-object-metadata.html), to add `Cache-Control` headers to `_next/static` objects metadata:

1. Open the Amazon S3 console and your bucket.
2. Select the check box to the left of the `_next/` directory.
3. On the Actions menu, choose Edit actions, and choose Edit metadata.
4. Choose Add metadata.
5. For metadata Type, select System-defined.
6. Select `Cache-Control` for the key and add `max-age=31536000,public,immutable` as the value.
7. When you are done, hit Save Changes and Amazon S3 should edit all the `_next/static` files metadata recursively, you can verify it by opening a specific file and scrolling down to the metadata section.

##### With CDK

If you are using AWS CDK you can use multiple `BucketDeployment` constructs to specify different `Cache-Control` headers for different `out` directories  (see [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment-readme.html#prune)):

```js
// _next/static - long max-age & immutable content
new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'BucketDeployment', {
  ...
  sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./out', { exclude: [ '/**/*', '!/_next/static/**/*'] })],
  cacheControl: [s3deploy.CacheControl.fromString('max-age=31536000,public,immutable')],
  ...
});

// revalidate everything else
new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'BucketDeployment', {
  ...
  sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./out', { exclude: ['/_next/static/**/*'] })],
  cacheControl: [s3deploy.CacheControl.fromString('max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate')],
  ...
});
```

##### Improving without Vercel

I'd also suggest (if using some additional AWS resources and terraform is not an issue) taking a look at this [terraform module](https://github.com/milliHQ/terraform-aws-next-js) or very least their image optimizer which can be dropped in as a standalone image optimization loader for the Next.js image component, so you get all the `next/image` component benefits (there's also this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19065) for bunch of other workarounds).